# Как в WPF правильно создавать Меню придерживаясь паттерна MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В MainView.xaml

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Menu Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="Файл">
            <MenuItem Header="Выход"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Правка" >
            <MenuItem Header="Очистить "></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Данные" RenderTransformOrigin="0.649,1.833" >
            <MenuItem Header="Пункт 1" Command="{Binding ReferenceDataClickCommand}" ToolTip="Получить справочные данные"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Пункт 2" ToolTip="Получить справочные данные"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Пункт 3" ToolTip="Получить справочные данные"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Справка" ></MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

Нужно для каждого пункта делать свой Binding?

```
 <MenuItem Header="Данные" RenderTransformOrigin="0.649,1.833" >
            <MenuItem Header="Пункт 1" Command="{Binding FirstMenuItemClickCommand}" ToolTip="Получить справочные данные"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Пункт 2" Command="{Binding SecondMenuItemClickCommand}"  ToolTip="Получить справочные данные"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Пункт 3" Command="{Binding ThirdMenuItemClickCommand}" ToolTip="Получить справочные данные"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
```

Или можно как-то универсально?

```
     <MenuItem Header="Данные" RenderTransformOrigin="0.649,1.833" >
            <MenuItem Header="Пункт 1" Command="{Binding MenuItemClickCommand}" ToolTip="Получить справочные данные"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Пункт 2" Command="{Binding MenuItemClickCommand}"  ToolTip="Получить справочные данные"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Пункт 3" Command="{Binding MenuItemClickCommand}" ToolTip="Получить справочные данные"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
```

и далее из MainViewModel.cs как-то получить значение Header?

Ключевой вопрос  "**как правильно**". То, что выше - мои предположения и наблюдения.

Answer (score 0):

Ну зависит от твоих целей - в целом нет ничего зазорного, чтобы ручками в xaml запилить, если меню статичное. Можно на каждый пункт свою команду вешать, а можно одну команду сделать и передавать параметром (`CommandParameter`) ид кнопки - и там уже обрабатывать - хотя спорный вариант, не берусь рекомендовать так делать, разве что для некоторых однотипных команд... хм..

Можно через биндинги динамически меню сделать. Вот так:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public List<MenuItemViewModel> Menu { get; set; }
    public string Title => "MenuExample";


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var fileMenu = new List<MenuItemViewModel>
        {
            new MenuItemViewModel("Сохранить", new RelayCommand(() => { System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Saved");}))
        };

        Menu = new List<MenuItemViewModel>
        {
            new MenuItemViewModel("Файл", null, fileMenu),
            new MenuItemViewModel("Выход", new RelayCommand(()=> {System.Environment.Exit(0);}))
        };
    }
}

public class MenuItemViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public RelayCommand Command { get; set; }

    public List<MenuItemViewModel> Submenu { get; set; }

    public MenuItemViewModel () 
    {
        Submenu = new List<MenuItemViewModel> ();
    }

    public MenuItemViewModel (string title, RelayCommand command, List<MenuItemViewModel> submenu = null) {
        Title = title;
        Command = command;

        Submenu = submenu ?? new List<MenuItemViewModel> ();
    }
}
```

в xaml:

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}">
    <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Menu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:MenuItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Submenu}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemTemplate>
</Menu>
```

Учтите тут все в лоб и грубо сделано - просто концепт =)